# Angular Reactive Forms - Filtering list with both text search and toggle

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

[image: Filtered List]

I have the below setup. The search input box works great. I have now added the toggle and I am trying to understand how to make both work together.

I have created a BehaviourSubject & Observable combination for the search term then am watching the observable to trigger the filtering of the object.

```
searchString = new BehaviorSubject("");
searchString$ = this.searchString.asObservable();   


this.myForm.controls.searchString.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  tap((val) => this.searchString.next(val))
).subscribe()


this.searchString$.subscribe((searchTerm) => {
  console.log(this.userNames);
  if (this.userNames !== undefined) {
    this.filteredUserNames = this.userNames.filter(
      (userName) =>
        userName.searchTerms
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    );
  };
```

This works fine. Now I have the toggle set up with a formcontrolname and Valuechanges observable

```
this.myForm.controls.isActive.valueChanges.pipe(
  tap( val => this.userIsActive = val)
).subscribe()
```

This toggles the userIsActive. In filteredUserNames I have a property `isActive: boolean`

What is the best way to filter the filteredUserNames object by both the searchTerm and the isActive state?

**EDIT:**
The users object looks like this

```
{id: 52, firstName: "Administrator", lastName: "Account", employeeId: null, jobTitle: "Learning Administrator", isActive: false …}
```

The filteredUserNames list is used as in a *ngFor in the template.

```
<div (click)="selectUser(userName)" 
    *ngFor="let userName of filteredUserNames">
     {{userName.title}}
     etc...
</div
```

*I need to filter the list with both filters isActive and SearchTerm. So if the inactive is switched to false then the search box will only search the inactive list and if it is switched to true the search box will search the whole original list.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an endpoint, FormGroup will return its full value

```
destroy$ = new Subject<any>();

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            // To clear valueChanges
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
            debounceTime(400),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            // This will take a val and switch to an endpoint of a choice
            switchMap((val) => this.onSearch(val))
        ).subscribe(res => { });
}

private onSearch() {
    return {{ endPoint }}
};
```

if its a local search make `switchMap` back to `tap` and do some local filtering with an object of form value

Comment: I'm trying to understand ngOnDestroy and why it is necessary here.

Comment: @Bwizard it's not in this particular case with a local subject. but it is a good practice to do anyway.  also `distinctUntilChanged()` isn't doing anything in this example as with the full group the comparison will always fail.

Comment: Well, its not. You see, component has a state when its destroyed but the `valueChanges` returns `Subject` that doesn`t. That`s just a small performance advice. There are exceptions, like `activatedRoute` or `http` auto-completes itself on value return. Feel free not to include the destroy part. Did it work for you btw?

Comment: OK I'm still getting my head around this. The original subscription to the full group gets fired when either the toggle or the input field is changed. How do I apply the debounceTime and distinctUntil Changed only if the input box is changed and not if the toggle is toggled?

Comment: Maybe I don't need to be concerned with this as it does not matter with a toggle. The switchMap documentation says it switches to another observable. I'm not sure I see another observable.

Comment: @Bwizard can you please provide us with information how the value of those inputs will be used in the future?

Comment: this.myForm.valueChanges returns the object `{searchString: "", isActive: true}` I am struggling with how to filter my list with both values. So it is the actual filtering part that I am trying to figure out.

Comment: `this.filteredUserNames = this.userNames.filter((userName) => userName.searchTerms
.toLowerCase()
 .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1);`  This filters the userName list with the search string and saves it in the filteredUserNames variable. But what if I also want to filter that list with isActive false. I am filtering an already filtered list.

Comment: I dont think its related to the topic anymore, but it depends on where is the `isActive` property on your user and how do you display your users.

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I do think that the way you do it is far more complicated that it sholud be `this.filteredUsers = this.users.filter((user) =>
      user.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(formValue.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      && user.isActive === formValue.isActive
    );` Where `filteredUsers ` is an array of users, `users` all the users, formValue is a value from a form change

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could simplify that:

```
const searchTerm = val.searchString.toLowerCase();

const list = val.isActive ? this.userNames : this.userNames.filter(user => 
     user.isDeleted === false
);

this.filteredUserNames = list.filter((userName) => 
    userName.searchTerms.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from @Dima S's answer I used the full form group value changes then created alternative searches based on whether the list was active or inactive.

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  tap( val => 
    {
      if (val.isActive == false) {
        let searchTerm = val.searchString;
        let isInactiveList = this.userNames.filter(user => user.isDeleted == false)
        this.filteredUserNames = isInactiveList.filter((userName) =>
        userName.searchTerms
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
      } 
      else if (val.isActive == true) {
        let searchTerm = val.searchString;
        this.filteredUserNames = this.userNames.filter((userName) =>
        userName.searchTerms
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
      }
    })
).subscribe()
```